# Building iPhone App for Distribution

Tags: iphone

I have a question on how exactly to do the final distribution build for my app. I have actually successfully built this app already but now I am trying to make an updated version and to remember what I did right the first time. It all seemed to go wrong when my provisioning profile expired....

Anyway, I have my distribution certificate and distribution provisioning profile. I have followed the instructions from Apple, an iPhone programming book and several online sources to create a build that checks against the right certificate etc. But the build always fails unless I connect a device, which is strange as the distribution provisioning profiles do not allow the inclusion of a device (which makes perfect sense in itself). However when I build with a device connected I am asked

> 'Can’t run XXX on the iPod “iPod
>   touch”
>
> The iPod “iPod touch” doesn’t have the
>   provisioning profile with which the
>   application was signed.
>
> Click “Install and Run” to install the
>   provisioning profile XXX on “iPod
>   touch” and continue running XXX.'

When I click install and run it fails with the message that

> A valid provisioning profile for this
>   executable was not found.

So my basic question is how exactly should the final distribution build be done? An new executable appears, but it has a forbidden symbol on top of the application icon suggesting the build was unsuccessful.

Any help massively appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't click "Build and Go".

Either just build, and then locate the app and upload it, or use Xcode's "Build and Archive" option.

It is best to use "Build and Archive" as Xcode will look after the app bundle, and the important `.dSYM` file which is used to symbolicate crash reports for your app.

Comment: Fantastic! I was also able to upload the app directly from XCode to iTunes Connect from there. Thanks very much indeed for the help!

Comment: Good to hear :) If my answer was helpful, would you kindly consider marking it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

And you cannot upload and execute app that signed with 'Distribution' certificate on your device. Such app can only be uploaded to AppStore.